# Android guessing game? How to change the random number when user gets it right and solve crash fix when user enters nothing?

Tags: javascript, android, random

I'm trying to create a random number generator on Android Studio using JScript. The app works but it crashes when the user enters nothing and also it doesn't change the random number until the user restarts the app. 
I've tried the code below :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        int randomNumber;
        public void checkGuess(View view){
            EditText guessedNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guessedNumber);
            String guessedNumberString = guessedNumber.getText().toString();
            int guessedNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(guessedNumberString);
            String message = "";

            if (guessedNumberInt>randomNumber){
                message = "Too large!";
            }else if(guessedNumberInt<randomNumber){
                message = "Too small!";
            }else {
                message = "correct!";
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(21);
    }
}
```

What I should do to change the random number when user guesses it right and how to fix the app crash when user enters nothing?

Comment: Check if "guessedNumberString " is empty and if it's empty return.

Comment: that is because you are generating your random number inside your onCreate it'll only generate one time when your app starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make  Random randomGenerator global. The issue is you are only generating random number one time.onCreate will be called only ones.You need to create a random number each time guess is called.

Change your `onCreate` like this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        randomGenerator = new Random();

    }
}
```

And change your checkGuess method like this

```
        public void checkGuess(View view){
            int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(21);
            EditText guessedNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guessedNumber);
            String guessedNumberString = guessedNumber.getText().toString();
           if(TextUtils.isEmpty(guessedNumberString)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
           }
            int guessedNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(guessedNumberString);
            String message = "";



            if (guessedNumberInt>randomNumber){
                message = "Too large!";
            }else if(guessedNumberInt<randomNumber){
                message = "Too small!";
            }else {
                message = "correct!";
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here use this to solve your problem:

```
public void checkGuess(View view){
            EditText guessedNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.guessedNumber);

            String guessedNumberString = guessedNumber.getText().toString();
        String message = "";
            int guessedNumberInt =0;
            if (guessedNumberString.length() > 0){
                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(21);
                guessedNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(guessedNumberString);
                if (guessedNumberInt>randomNumber){
                    message = "Too large!";
                }else if(guessedNumberInt<randomNumber){
                    message = "Too small!";
                }else {
                    message = "correct!";
                }

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            }else{
                //show message to enter a value
            }
    }
```